# Image went black when trying to convert HSB to RGB

Tags: java, image, image-processing, colors

I already had Hue Saturation and Brightness value in each array.
After I adjust the brightness for each pixel (with exposure compensation method), I want to repaint it to RGB with this:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

     int rgb;
    Training ns = new Training();
    JLabel TempL = new JLabel("Temperature");
    JLabel ExpoL = new JLabel("Exposure");
    JLabel SatuL = new JLabel("Saturation");
    JSlider Temp = new JSlider(-50, 50, 0);
    JSlider Expo = new JSlider(-50, 50, 0);
    JSlider Satu = new JSlider(-50, 50, 0);
    JPanel sg = new JPanel();
    HSB hsb = new HSB();
    int a, b; 

    public MainFrame () {


        setSize(1200, 700);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        sg.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (250, 600));
        sg.setLayout(new BoxLayout(sg, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        sg.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 75)));
        sg.add(TempL);
        sg.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 15)));
        sg.add(Temp);
        sg.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 75)));
        sg.add(ExpoL);
        sg.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 15)));
        sg.add(Expo);

        Expo.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener () {
                           public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {  
                           JSlider Expo = (JSlider) evt.getSource();
                            if (Expo.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                            ns.value2 = (float) Expo.getValue()/100;

                            for(a = 0; a < ns.image.getWidth(); a++ ) {
                                for(b = 0; b < ns.image.getHeight(); b++ ) {

                                    hsb.shue[a][b] = hsb.hue[a][b];
                                    hsb.ssaturation[a][b] = hsb.saturation[a][b];
                                    hsb.sbrightness[a][b] = hsb.brightness[a][b];

                                            }
                                        }

                            for(ns.forT1 = 0; ns.forT1 < ns.image.getWidth(); ns.forT1++ ) {
                            for(ns.forT2 = 0; ns.forT2 < ns.image.getHeight(); ns.forT2++ ) {
                            hsb.sbrightness[ns.forT1][ns.forT2] = (float) (hsb.sbrightness[ns.forT1][ns.forT2] * (Math.pow(ns.value2, 2)));
                                if (hsb.sbrightness[ns.forT1][ns.forT2] > 1) {
                                    hsb.sbrightness[ns.forT1][ns.forT2] = 1;
                                            }
                                if (hsb.sbrightness[ns.forT1][ns.forT2] < 0) {
                                    hsb.sbrightness[ns.forT1][ns.forT2] = 0;
                                            }
                            rgb = Color.HSBtoRGB(hsb.shue[ns.forT1][ns.forT2], hsb.ssaturation[ns.forT1][ns.forT2], hsb.sbrightness[ns.forT1][ns.forT2]);
                            ns.image.setRGB(ns.forT1, ns.forT2, rgb);

                                        }  
                                        } 
                                    } 

                            validate();
                            repaint();  
                                  } 

                            });

        add(ns);
        add(sg, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the image just went black right after I move the slider.
Is there any flaw in my calculations?